# Hexadecimal String to ByteArray in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, hex, byte

How can I convert hexadecimal string to a ByteArray object in Kotlin?
I tried to find a answer on StackOverflow, but I was only able to find answers on how to convert ByteArrays to hexadecimal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin convert hex string to ByteArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66613717/kotlin-convert-hex-string-to-bytearray)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any solution for java would work for kotlin, here is the sample code
For big numbers you can use `BigInteger` and its constructor with hex radix

```
val bytearray: ByteArray = BigInteger("1D08A", 16).toByteArray()
```