# InvalidKeyException: invalid key format

Tags: kotlin, rsa

I'm trying to encrypt plain texts with public key.
My code keeps fail with InvalidKeyException.
This is my code:

```kotlin
private const val pubkey = "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"
private val cipher: Cipher

init {
    val bytesKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(pubkey)
    val keySpec = X509EncodedKeySpec(bytesKey)
    val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
    val publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec)  // where exception has been thrown

    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey)
}

fun encrypt(plainText: String): String {
    val bytePlain = cipher.doFinal(plainText.toByteArray())
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytePlain)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pubkey` contains the hex encoded key, i.e. for the initialization of `bytesKey` a hex decoding is necessary and no Base64 decoding.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66613717) you can find an implementation for a hex decoding for Kotlin.

Note also that when instantiating the cipher, it is better to specify the padding besides the algorithm, e.g. `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding`, otherwise the provider dependent default padding is applied, which may be a different one than you expect.