# Decrypt facebook install referrer data , Android

Tags: android, facebook, cryptography, install-referrer

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/install-referrer/
Facebook uses AES-GCM 256bit symmetric key using LibSodium to encrypt their referrer data.
And i am trying to decrypt them on Android.

Facebook Example :
$key = "2575590594a9cd809e5bfacf397f8c1ac730dbc38a3e137ecd1ab66591c8c3c9"
$cipher = "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";
$nonce = "b7203c6a6fb633d16e9cf5c1";

However when i start to decrypt this on Android, i get an exception:
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Unsupported key size: 64 bytes (must be 16 or 32)
How am i supposed to decrypt using AES GCM with a 64 bytes facebook key ?

```
    val message =
        "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".toByteArray()

    val key = "2575590594a9cd809e5bfacf397f8c1ac730dbc38a3e137ecd1ab66591c8c3c9".toByteArray()
    val mKey = SecretKeySpec(key, "AES/GCM/NoPadding")

    val nonce = "b7203c6a6fb633d16e9cf5c1".toByteArray()
    val mNonce = IvParameterSpec(nonce)
    val c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, mKey, mNonce)
    val original = String(c.doFinal(message))
```

Comment: The data are hex encoded, you have to hex decode them. Then data can be decrypted: `{"ad_id": "12345",...`. For further support post your Android code.

Comment: Done, thank you @Topaco, i was not even successful to make it read the key.

Comment: You just need to hex decode `message`, `key` and `nonce`, e.g. `val message = "af...79".decodeHex()`, s. [`decodeHex()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66614516/9014097).

Comment: Hi.. Did you get any solution? How to decrypt this data?

Comment: Yes i did sorry just read your message