# J8583 - Set Header in BCD

Tags: java, kotlin, iso8583, j8583

How to make header in BCD rather than HEX?

```
val isoRequest: IsoMessage = msgFactory.newMessage(0x800)
isoRequest.isoHeader = "6003000000"

log(isoRequest.writeData().bytesToHex())
```

Currently the above code will generate

```
363030333030303030300800
```

What we need is something like this

```
60030000000800
```

Comment: byte-wise and with `0x0F`?! (inspired by your username)

Comment: BCD text to bytes, is the same as hex text to bytes, two characters "60" becoming byte 0x60. So I would have expected to see `hexToBytes()`. Java 17 has a standard conversion, but see the entire https://stackoverflow.com/a/140861/984823

Comment: @JoopEggen, ooh so the term for ASCII that is padded with 0 in order to become 2 bytes like HEX is called BCD text?

Comment: In BCD every digit 0-9 is stored as 4 bits in a 8 bits byte half. In hexadecimal every digit 0-9A-F is stored as 4 bits in a byte half too. So a byte 0x69 has two digits "69".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need [`isoRequest.setBinaryIsoHeader`](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.sf.j8583/j8583/latest/com/solab/iso8583/IsoMessage.html)

e.g. (code in java):

```java
isoRequest.setBinaryIsoHeader(new byte[] {0x60, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00});
```

The string version sets the ASCII representation of the string characters.

You can also get the byte array from a hex string in kotlin using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76830156/3444205